# Rails routes, url and subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, subdomain

My ruby app is divided in different namespaces.
like: free(free.domain.com), pro(pro.domain.com), vip(vip.domain.com)
In the routes file looks like this:

```
namespace :free do
  match 'home' => 'free#home', :via => [:get, :post], :as => :home
  #more routes
end

namespace :pro do
  match 'home' => 'pro#home', :via => [:get, :post], :as => :home
  #more routes
end

namespace :vip do
  match 'home' => 'vip#home', :via => [:get, :post], :as => :home
  #more routes
end

match '/about'                => 'pages#about'
match '/team'                 => 'pages#team'
match '/press'                => 'pages#press'
#more routes
```

I would like that wherever I am in the app when there is a link like pro_home_path, the url be pro.domain.com/home.

So basically, is it possible in the routes file to add a subdomain(something like this `namespace :vip, :subdomain => vip do`) to append the subdomain to the corresponding namespace?

**EDIT:** So I have added a `constraint constraints(:subdomain => "newsfeed") do`

But the link when I do pro_home_path, I'm getting lvh.me/3000/pro/home instead of pro.lvh.me:3000/home

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a subdomain as a constraint, e.g.

```
get 'photos', constraints: {subdomain: 'admin'}
```

Check out the rails guide on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

To link to a specific subdomain, you can specify it in a URL route helper. For example, `home_url(subdomain: 'pro')` might redirect to `http://pro.example.com/home`. Take care to use the `_url` suffixed methods as `home_path` will not redirect to a specific subdomain.

Comment: I edited my post with a constrain but it doesn't redirect to a subdomain.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a solution to that. I don't believe there is a 'prettier' way to do it without writing your own helpers or finding a gem that does this.