# Spree commerce admin to a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In Spree Commerce how can I set admin link to a subdomain.

the existing is http://example.org/admin to access the admin

I want to do is http://admin.example.org to access the admin page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spree is just a rails application.  You can configure your routes in your routes.rb file. Here is another stackoverflow question about the same thing and rails routing guide:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21537230/785050
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

`get '/', to: 'admin/root#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }`